# A regex to match this or exactly that

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

I am tryign to write a Markdown Parser ontop of the LDT JavaScript plugin, that allows a sort-of real-time parsing. It has basic functions and one of them is a custom parser that uses Regex.

While trying to implement a Markdown "parser", I got stuck on lists. I want to match

```
- This string
* and that string
```

Or exactly

```
1. A string that starts with a number whic must be followed by a period.
```

So, when creating the parser, all the entries are concationated and separated with a pipe (`|`). The template is: `new Regexp("^("+s+")$")`.

My current Regex to match unordered lists:

```
 /[-\*]\s[^\n\r]*\n?/
```

...but this does also match in the center of a line.

What is the regex to match either `-` or `*` prefixed strings, or number prefixed strings, but which must have a period?

Comment: Why don't give us your Input and your desired Output for short? :D

Comment: Regex isn't recommended for parsing.  Regex is a small pattern engine.  This question can be answered, but in the long run, parsing Markdown with Regex probably isn't your best bet.

Comment: Does this work: [`/^([-*]|\d\.)\s(.*)$/gm`](https://regex101.com/r/fL5tK4/2)

Comment: Sam: This matches numbered lines with no period at the end. Mine is not elegant, but you can try. [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/jU3sU9/1)

Comment: You mix metaphors with your description. don't say _template_ is some regex syntax, it isn't. This `^("+s+")$"` is very obscure. I'm pretty sure you can parse anything with regular expressions. Many times it's in stages.

Comment: @SzabolcsDézsi I'm pretty sure the "followed by a period" is referring to the period right after the number. So: `1. foo` but not `2 bar`...

Comment: @sln I didn't use regex before like I have to now. So if I get some word or metaphor wrong, I am really sorry. English isn't even my main language. :) I was refering to [this line of code.](https://github.com/kueblc/LDT/blob/master/lib/Parser.js#L21)

Comment: @Jamen I am not trying to parse it perfectly - this serves as previewing the the output in a minimal way. It gives the author an idea if what he/she is typing is at least valid. The real parsing happens using Parsedown anyway. So yes, I am aware of the issues when using Regex with Markdown :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoiding the discussion if this is the right/wrong way to approach your desired task, you could use two [group captures and beginning/end line boundaries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp). The first group capture will allow you to test what type of list it is if there is a match.

```js
var strings = [
  '- This string',
  '* and that string',
  '1. A string that starts with a number which must be followed by a period.',
  'Bad string',
  '-Bad string', 
  '*Bad string',
  '2 Bad string.'
];

var matchRegExp = /^(\d\.|\*|\-)\s(.+)$/;

var res = strings.map(function (str) {
  return { str: str, match: str.match(matchRegExp) };
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(res, null, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: +1, but a couple notes for the picky: 1). `-` doesn't need to be escaped outside of a character class (and doesn't even need to be escaped as the first/last character in a class), 2). `\*|\-` could be shortened to `[*-]`, 3). the trailing `$` could be good for readability but is unnecessary when ending with a greedy dot-match-all.

Comment: @Sam Agreed but I was going for readability over style/performant considerations

Comment: @JasonCust Thanks a lot. That worked for me. I tested it using Nodejs on the ocmmand line and it matches what I want it to match. Thank you!